# XAML vs. Code-Behind: Storyboards and Animation

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, animation, storyboard

I've been scouring the internet and MSDN websites, trying to wrap my head around this whole animation deal, and I'm at a bit of a loss. I've seen examples wherein programmers will write all the animation biz into the code-behind files, and leave the XAML code relatively bare. On the other hand, I've seen the opposite, rarely, mind you, but I've seen it. What I'm trying to figure out when should you code in code-behind as opposed to using XAML. To add to that question consider this.

My biggest hurdle in learning the inner machinations of Storyboard and its ilk is the GetValue()-esque methods, and the deep binding principles. There aren't many sites that help get a full understanding of these concepts unless you have immaculate cryptography skills or a excellent gift of discernment (I'm looking at you, MSDN!). So for those still honing those skills (i.e. me) I need some references that give me a nitty-gritty understanding so that I go about on my own. Something past

`"{Binding Path=Text}"`

or something like that (although, this isn't fully explained either. they kind of gloss over the subtle stuff). I need stuff like

`"{Binding Path=(UIElement.Something.SomethingElse).(Property)}"`

with the details put in. Such as: Why do they use parentheses? Am I only supposed to used one level of dot reference in binding braces? Is there a limit that I can do within the parentheses? Etc.

Please apply it to this example: In XAML I currently have two animations two animate a path down below (... is for abridging code):

```
<Page x:Class="PhotoPage"
      ...
      ...
      >
    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Storyboard x:Key="RAnim_P1_2">
                <DoubleAnimation x:Name="X"
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="ReactorP1_2SclX"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                                 Duration="0:0:2" From="1.0" To="15.0"
                                 />
                <DoubleAnimation x:Name="Y"
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="ReactorP1_2SclX"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                                 Duration="0:0:2" From="1.0" To="15.0"
                                 />
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="RAnim_P1_22">
                <DoubleAnimation x:Name="BX"
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="ReactorP1_2SclX"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                                 Duration="0:0:2" From="15.0" To="1.0"
                                 />
                <DoubleAnimation x:Name="BY"
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="ReactorP1_2SclX"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                                 Duration="0:0:2" From="15.0" To="1.0"
                                 />
            </Storyboard>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>
   ...
   ...
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid>
                <Path x:Name="ReactorP1_2"
                  Data="F0 M 0,0 C 0,1.44 0,3.52 0,4.8 -0.96,4.8 -1.92,4.8 -2.4,4.8
                  ...
                  ..."
                  Fill="#ffff0000" Stretch="Fill"
                  Canvas.Left="164.609" Canvas.Top="44.15" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Path.RenderTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="ReactorP1_2SclX" ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="1.0"/>
                    </Path.RenderTransform>
                </Path>
            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

While in my in related code-behind file, I have this:

```
Imports System.Windows.Media.Animation

Class PhotoPage

    Dim NR_Running As Boolean = False

    Private Sub ToggleScale_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles AnimateNR.Click
        NR_Running = Not NR_Running
        Dim strybrd1 As New Storyboard()
        strybrd1 = Me.Resources("RAnim_P1_2")
        Dim strybrd2 As New Storyboard()
        strybrd2 = Me.Resources("RAnim_P1_22")

        Dim anim1 = strybrd1.Children("X")

        If strybrd1 IsNot Nothing Then
            If strybrd2 IsNot Nothing Then
                If NR_Running Then
                    strybrd1.Begin()
                Else
                    strybrd2.Begin()
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

This code is supposed to make the path increase in size at the click of a button in the page. That works. It also makes the path shrink when you click the button again. However, I want something extra. When I click the button while it's growing, I would like the animation to turn around right where it is and begin shrinking, and vice-versa. Currently, when I click during the animation it will skip to the end of the currently-running animation, and then begin to shrink, making the shape "pop", so to speak, and not make a smooth transition from growing to shrinking. I'd like it to be smooth.

The way I see this working is to access the animation within the storyboard, set the `To` of the a new animation to the `From` of the running one, then set the `TargetProperty` value of the running animation to the `From` of the new one. Then, set the `Duration` of the new one to the difference between the "base duration" and the "current time" of the running one. Then make the new one run. However, I don't know how to access the animations from code-behind, which needs to happen, as this entire thing runs from a button click.

Once helped with this, I should be able to know how to use the GetValue() method of the StoryBoard class to fetch the properties of its Animation children, as well as be able to bind some `TextBlock`s to those Animation properties, just so I can see if they update in real-time.

Sorry this is so long-winded, but I have been working on this for two days, and I have no way of how to make this query concise. I'm not sure if I've even explained it well. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: The parentheses are explained in [PropertyPath XAML Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: You should give a try in using Blend for sketching animations using the mouse, you will see what XAML code it generates.

Comment: @Clemens That's fine and all, but if you remember from the post, these MSDN pages are difficult for me to read, with them throwing around buzz words. On top of that, this does not solve my current problem. I don't know how to access the Double Animation within the StoryBoard by using the StoryBoard, if that's possible. I was thinking StoryBoard.GetValue() or something.